# How do I check if a method returns true or false in an IF statement in Java?

Tags: java, methods, if-statement, boolean

Let's say I have a boolean method that uses an *if* statement to check whether the return type should be *true* or *false*:

```
public boolean isValid() {
   boolean check;
   int number = 5;

   if (number > 4){
      check = true;
   } else {
      check = false;
   }

 return check;
```

And now, I want to use this method as a parameter of an *if* statement in a **different** method:

```
if(isValid == true)  // <-- this is where I'm not sure
   //stop and go back to the beginning of the program
else
   //continue on with the program
```

So basically what I'm asking is, how do I check what the return type of the boolean method within the parameters of an if statement is? Your answers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: How about - `if (ifValid())`. And your method will always return `true`, if you notice it.

Comment: yes you are going in a right way... :)

Comment: A little off topic, but stumbling across this question reminds me of how far I've come as a programmer. Great feeling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it's a method, to call it you should use parens afterwards, so your code would then become:

```
if(isValid()) {
    // something
} else {
    //something else
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add the "== true" here.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isValid() {
   int number = 5;
   return number > 4;
}
```

```
if (isValid()) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just call the function within the IF condition so:

```
if (isValid()) {

}else {

}
```

Since `isValid()` returns a `boolean` the condition will be evaluated right away. I have heard it is better form to create a local var just before you test you condition.

```
 boolean tempBoo = isValid();

 if (tempBoo) {

 }else {

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**-** `If` statement **accepts only** `boolean` value.

```
public boolean isValid() {

   boolean check = false;   // always intialize the local variable
   int number = 5;

   if (number > 4){
      check = true;
   } else {
      check = false;
   }

 return check;

}


if(isValid()){

    // Do something if its true
}else{

    // Do something if its false
}
```

Comment: great answer will full working and init of variables, sometimes when the mind is working slowly these kind of answers make the day...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isValid()) {
   // do something when the method returned true
} else {
   // do something else when the method returned false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if(isValid()){
     //do something....
}
else
{
    //do something....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isValid() {
   boolean check;
   int number = 5;

   if (number > 4){
      check = true;
   } else {
      check = false;
   }

 return check;
```

How can you do this whole method without boolean check?

So how to get rid of.. check = true, check = false, return check stuff?

Comment: You can return just the evaluation itself, as ‘return number > 4;’ That will condense your method into fewer lines.